# Java - what is the best way to check if a STRING contains only certain characters?

Tags: java, regex, string, char

I have this problem: I have a `String`, but I need to make sure that it *only* contains letters **A-Z** and numbers **0-9**. Here is my current code:

```
boolean valid = true;
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
    int type = Character.getType(c);
    if (type == 2 || type == 1 || type == 9) {
        // the character is either a letter or a digit
    } else {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

But what is the best and the most efficient way to implement it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [regexes](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)?

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: if you don't want to use `regex` use predefined function of `Character` wrapper class. Convert your string `toCharArray` then use loop and use the predefined methods

Comment: Do you really want 0-9, or do you want any digit, even [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0663/index.htm)?

Comment: I believe OpenCL would help a lot about this :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since no one else has worried about "fastest" yet, here is my contribution:

```
boolean valid = true;

char[] a = s.toCharArray();

for (char c: a)
{
    valid = ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) || 
            ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) || 
            ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'));

    if (!valid)
    {
        break;
    }
}

return valid;
```

Full test code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] testStrings = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", "", "00000", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&", "1", "q", "test123", "(#*$))&v", "ABC123", "hello", "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"};

    long startNanos = System.nanoTime();

    for (String testString: testStrings)
    {
        isAlphaNumericOriginal(testString);
    }

    System.out.println("Time for isAlphaNumericOriginal: " + (System.nanoTime() - startNanos) + " ns"); 

    startNanos = System.nanoTime();

    for (String testString: testStrings)
    {
        isAlphaNumericFast(testString);
    }

    System.out.println("Time for isAlphaNumericFast: " + (System.nanoTime() - startNanos) + " ns");

    startNanos = System.nanoTime();

    for (String testString: testStrings)
    {
        isAlphaNumericRegEx(testString);
    }

    System.out.println("Time for isAlphaNumericRegEx: " + (System.nanoTime() - startNanos) + " ns");

    startNanos = System.nanoTime();

    for (String testString: testStrings)
    {
        isAlphaNumericIsLetterOrDigit(testString);
    }

    System.out.println("Time for isAlphaNumericIsLetterOrDigit: " + (System.nanoTime() - startNanos) + " ns");      
}

private static boolean isAlphaNumericOriginal(String s)
{
    boolean valid = true;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) 
    {
        int type = Character.getType(c);
        if (type == 2 || type == 1 || type == 9) 
        {
            // the character is either a letter or a digit
        }
        else 
        {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}

private static boolean isAlphaNumericFast(String s)
{
    boolean valid = true;

    char[] a = s.toCharArray();

    for (char c: a)
    {
        valid = ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) || 
                ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) || 
                ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'));

        if (!valid)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}

private static boolean isAlphaNumericRegEx(String s)
{
    return Pattern.matches("[\\dA-Za-z]+", s);
}

private static boolean isAlphaNumericIsLetterOrDigit(String s)
{
    boolean valid = true;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Produces this output for me:

```
Time for isAlphaNumericOriginal: 164960 ns
Time for isAlphaNumericFast: 18472 ns
Time for isAlphaNumericRegEx: 1978230 ns
Time for isAlphaNumericIsLetterOrDigit: 110315 ns
```

Comment: +1. I like this solution.  How did it compare to my solution?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc:  I've updated my answer to include your solution.  Looks like yours is about 6x slower than mine, the pattern matching solution is 107x slower, and the original solution is about 9x slower.  One thing I could do with the regex solution is pre-compile the pattern.  I've tried this and it does speed it up some, but it still ends up being 40x slower.

Comment: This is the most straighforward solution I've seen, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to avoid regex, then the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class can help:

```
boolean valid = true;
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) { 
    if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
    {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you care about being upper case, then do below if statement instead:

```
if(!((Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) || Character.isDigit(c)))
```

Comment: This would accept lower case letters and potentially letter/number characters from other character sets (anything considered a letter or digit in the Unicode \u0000 - \uFFFF) range.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to all the other answers, here's a Guava approach:

```
boolean valid = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.matchesAllOf(string);
```

More on CharMatcher: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher

Answer (score 3):

StringUtils in Apache Commons Lang 3 has a containsOnly method, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

The implementation should be fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html):

```
Pattern.matches("[\\dA-Z]+", string)
```

`[\\dA-Z]+`: At least one occurrence (+) of digits or uppercase letters.

If you want to include lowercase letter, replace `[\\dA-Z]+` with `[\\dA-Za-z]+`.

Comment: Still returns 'true' with "!username"

Comment: This checks whether it contains at least one digit or upper case letter, not that it contains only digits and upper case letters.

Comment: Need to specify start and end of string `^$` to get only digits/letters

Comment: But how do I check if a string is ONLY made out of numbers and letters?

Comment: Arguably the best solution in terms of simplicity and elegance.  Arguably the worst in terms of "fastest".

Comment: Not the fastest solution

Comment: Not necessarily the fastest, but the most flexible.

Comment: It's an order of magnitude slower than the posted method.  See my answer below for run times.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache Commons Lang:

```
StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(String)
```

Comment: Yes.  StringUtils is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

The following way is not as fast as Regular expression to implement but is one of the most efficient solution (I think) because it use bitwise operations which are really fast.

My solution is more complex and harder to read and maintain but I think it is another simple way to do what you want.

A good way to test that a string only contains numbers or capital letters is with a simple `128 bits bitmask` (2 Longs) representing the ASCII table.

So, For the standard ASCII table, there's a 1 on every character we want to keep (bit 48 to 57 and bit 65 to 90)

Thus, you can test that a char is a:

1. Number with this mask: `0x3FF000000000000L` (if the character code < 65)
2. Uppercase letter with this mask: `0x3FFFFFFL` (if the character code >=65)

So the following method should work:

```
public boolean validate(String aString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++) {
        char c = aString.charAt(i);

        if ((c <= 64) & ((0x3FF000000000000L & (1L << c)) == 0) 
                | (c > 64) & ((0x3FFFFFFL & (1L << (c - 65))) == 0)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  The only thing I would offer is that this solution only handles upper case characters.

Comment: Yes because it was specified in the question: "I need to make sure that it only contains letters A-Z".

Comment: Fair enough.  By the way, I compared your solution to the others I did in my answer above and it does indeed eke out the top spot.  18659 ns for my solution, and 15861 ns for yours.  Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in sense of maintainability and simplicity is the already posted regular expression. Once familiar the this technic you know what to expect and it is very easy to widen the criteria if needed. Downside of this is the performance.

The fastest way to go is the Array approach. Checking if a character's numerical value falls in the wanted range ASCII A-Z and 0-9 is nearly speed of light. But the maintainability is bad. Simplicity gone.

You could use and java 7 switch case with char approach but that's just as bad as the second.

In the end, since we are talking about java, I would strongly suggest to use regular expressions.

Comment: I agree with you.  In most cases, regular expressions are the most readable and simple way of doing it.  However, if you are concerned about real-time performance, String pattern matching happens to be one of the things that can really bite you in the butt.  In this case, every last millisecond can count, and compiled Patterns using regular expressions can be a true performance hit.